# Can my rig setup guy somehow cheat me and transfer some of the mining cash to his wallet?

Tags: mining, bitcoin, rig

I am new with the mining thing and I have a question to ask regarding this. I have a guy that setup my rigs home and i want to be sure if he did the right thing or if somehow he is cheating me. I want to know if its possible for him to transfer somehow of my mining income to his wallet? And if so how i am able to protect myself from this?

Thanks,

Darko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, he can cheat.

To figure this out, do the following:

1. Review the configuration file of the miner (ask the guy to show it to you). Make sure all addresses their are yours.
2. Make sure that there are no [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) jobs that (re-)launch the miner process at specific times, e.g., late at night or at other times when you can't access the rig.
3. Track your income. Compare it to the expected income from mining revenue calculators (given your rig specifications). Significant discrepancies may be a sign of cheating.

The advise above doesn't provide a 100% guarantee, but is it better than nothing.